# Filemaker pro: how to make a report of a specific table field?

Tags: statistics, report, filemaker

I am a trainee at ministry of education where we fix schools' computers, I've created a table for this purpose using filemaker pro with the fields: school name, the problem, the date, who fixed it ...etc.
I would like to generate a report of a particular field, e.g: a report that will display how many times this particular school has brought its devices to get fixed. Or how many times this particular employee has fixed a device. and print the report .

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is to choose the command to create a new layout (View - Layout mode, then Layout - New Layout/Report), select the Report type and press Next. This will provide a wizard that asks a few questions about the report and even create a script to run the report.